# PyPI package can be searched using pip but cannot be installed. easy_install works fine

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, easy-install, pypi

I'm running into an issue where I execute `pip install python-sdk-auth`, and I get this error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-sdk-auth (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-sdk-auth`

This package was initially built by running:

`python setup.py bdist_egg --exclude-source-files`

to only contain `.pyc` files
and uploaded via this `twine`:

`twine upload dist/<packagename>.egg`

Here are more observations:

1. I'm able to `pip search python-sdk-auth` and the package seems to be present in the package directory.
2. I'm able to do `easy_install python-sdk-auth`, and the package will be installed successfully.
3. I'm running python v2.7.

It seems like I could do this via `easy_install`, but not on `pip`. My main intention is to have this package be a dependency of another package (as specified via the `install_requires` parameter in `setup.py`, but it seems like even installing this via `pip install` in a `virtualenv` environment throws an error above. Any suggestions on what went wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: follow up: does this have to do with pip vs easy_install using a different installation format when it was initially uploaded to PyPI? https://packaging.python.org/pip_easy_install/ See: Installation format in the comparison table.

Answer (score 1):

The only distribution for the package available on PyPI is an egg, an older format that is used by setuptools (and thus `easy_install`) but not pip.  Pip can only install packages from source distributions made with `sdist` (which every package should have) and from wheels (the replacement for the egg format, which should be preferred to eggs 99.9999% of the time).  Build & upload one (or, better, both) of these files to PyPI to make your package installable via pip.

Recommended further reading: https://packaging.python.org/distributing/

Comment: Ok cool. As a followup: Is there a way to distribute this package as just .pyc files via `bdist_wheel`? Is there a CLI option for this? (`bdist_egg` has --`exclude-source-files`) I can't seem to find one on the docs. Or do I need something like `Cython`? I know this isn't recommended, but I think it serves our use case "well enough" for now.

Comment: @tzhenghao: The metadata for your project says that you're releasing it under the MIT license, meaning it's open source.  If this project is truly open source, there should be no reason not to distribute the source files.  If you insist on trying to keep the source secret, I would recommend not trying to distribute it through PyPI at all, and my further thoughts on your endeavors would violate SO's "Be Nice" policy.

Comment: yeah I totally missed that. I'll change that right now